# Merging pandas DataFrames with overlapping indices and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames `df1` and `df2`. They have overlapping data in both index and column.

```
import yfinance as yf

symbols = ['QQQ', 'GBTC']
df1 = yf.download(symbols, start="2019-01-01", end="2019-01-07")

symbols = ['GBTC', 'TLT']
df2 = yf.download(symbols, start="2019-01-03", end="2019-01-15")
```

Here's the content of `df1`:

```
           Adj Close              Close              High               Low  \
                GBTC         QQQ   GBTC         QQQ  GBTC         QQQ  GBTC   
Date                                                                          
2018-12-31     3.965  152.132996  3.965  154.259995  4.15  154.979996  3.95   
2019-01-02     4.620  152.744461  4.620  154.880005  4.65  155.750000  4.13   
2019-01-03     4.520  147.754257  4.520  149.820007  4.62  153.259995  4.32   
2019-01-04     4.530  154.075851  4.530  156.229996  4.65  157.000000  4.41   

                         Open               Volume            
                   QQQ   GBTC         QQQ     GBTC       QQQ  
Date                                                          
2018-12-31  152.710007  4.140  154.470001  3829000  53015300  
2019-01-02  150.880005  4.155  150.990005  2948200  58576700  
2019-01-03  149.490005  4.325  152.600006  1503000  74820200  
2019-01-04  151.740005  4.585  152.339996  2020700  74709300
```

Here's `df2`:

```
           Adj Close             Close              High               Low  \
                GBTC         TLT  GBTC         TLT  GBTC         TLT  GBTC   
Date                                                                         
2019-01-02      4.62  117.461304  4.62  122.150002  4.65  122.160004  4.13   
2019-01-03      4.52  118.797966  4.52  123.540001  4.62  123.860001  4.32   
2019-01-04      4.53  117.422844  4.53  122.110001  4.65  122.559998  4.41   
2019-01-07      4.86  117.076653  4.86  121.750000  4.94  122.650002  4.74   
2019-01-08      4.96  116.768936  4.96  121.430000  5.08  121.940002  4.84   
2019-01-09      4.71  116.586197  4.71  121.239998  5.02  121.430000  4.63   
2019-01-10      4.32  115.836174  4.32  120.459999  4.46  121.410004  4.16   
2019-01-11      4.32  116.288139  4.32  120.930000  4.49  121.269997  4.25   
2019-01-14      4.47  115.855431  4.47  120.480003  4.55  121.010002  4.14   

                         Open               Volume            
                   TLT   GBTC         TLT     GBTC       TLT  
Date                                                          
2019-01-02  121.339996  4.155  121.660004  2948200  19841500  
2019-01-03  122.230003  4.325  122.290001  1503000  21187000  
2019-01-04  121.650002  4.585  122.339996  2020700  12970200  
2019-01-07  121.620003  4.740  122.620003  2676600   8498100  
2019-01-08  121.389999  4.895  121.690002  2653200   7737100  
2019-01-09  120.800003  5.015  121.260002  2778000   9349200  
2019-01-10  120.339996  4.455  121.279999  3799800   8222900  
2019-01-11  120.680000  4.410  120.830002  1218500   5786900  
2019-01-14  120.239998  4.145  120.900002  2581600   6730500
```

How can I merge `df1` and `df2` into `df3` so that `df3` has following contents?

```
> df3
         Adj Close                          Close                          \
                GBTC         QQQ         TLT   GBTC         QQQ         TLT   
Date                                                                          
2018-12-31     3.965  152.132996         NaN  3.965  154.259995         NaN 
2019-01-02     4.620  152.744461  117.461304  4.620  154.880005  122.150002    
2019-01-03     4.520  147.754257  118.797966  4.520  149.820007  123.540001 
2019-01-04     4.530  154.075851  117.422844  4.530  156.229996  122.110001   
2019-01-07     4.860         NaN  117.076653  4.860         NaN  121.750000   
2019-01-08     4.960         NaN  116.768936  4.960         NaN  121.430000   
2019-01-09     4.710         NaN  116.586197  4.710         NaN  121.239998   
2019-01-10     4.320         NaN  115.836174  4.320         NaN  120.459999   
2019-01-11     4.320         NaN  116.288139  4.320         NaN  120.930000   
2019-01-14     4.470         NaN  115.855431  4.470         NaN  120.480003   

            High                           Low                           Open  \
            GBTC         QQQ         TLT  GBTC         QQQ         TLT   GBTC   
Date                                                                            
2018-12-31  4.15  154.979996         NaN  3.95  152.710007         NaN  4.140    
2019-01-02  4.65  155.750000  122.160004  4.13  150.880005  121.339996  4.155     
2019-01-03  4.62  153.259995  123.860001  4.32  149.490005  122.230003  4.325    
2019-01-04  4.65  157.000000  122.559998  4.41  151.740005  121.650002  4.585   
2019-01-07  4.94         NaN  122.650002  4.74         NaN  121.620003  4.740   
2019-01-08  5.08         NaN  121.940002  4.84         NaN  121.389999  4.895   
2019-01-09  5.02         NaN  121.430000  4.63         NaN  120.800003  5.015   
2019-01-10  4.46         NaN  121.410004  4.16         NaN  120.339996  4.455   
2019-01-11  4.49         NaN  121.269997  4.25         NaN  120.680000  4.410   
2019-01-14  4.55         NaN  121.010002  4.14         NaN  120.239998  4.145   

                                     Volume                          
                   QQQ         TLT     GBTC         QQQ         TLT  
Date                                                                 
2018-12-31  154.470001         NaN  3829000  53015300.0         NaN  
2019-01-02  150.990005  121.660004  2948200  58576700.0  19841500.0  
2019-01-03  152.600006  122.290001  1503000  74820200.0  21187000.0  
2019-01-04  152.339996  122.339996  2020700  74709300.0  12970200.0  
2019-01-07         NaN  122.620003  2676600         NaN   8498100.0  
2019-01-08         NaN  121.690002  2653200         NaN   7737100.0  
2019-01-09         NaN  121.260002  2778000         NaN   9349200.0  
2019-01-10         NaN  121.279999  3799800         NaN   8222900.0  
2019-01-11         NaN  120.830002  1218500         NaN   5786900.0  
2019-01-14         NaN  120.900002  2581600         NaN   6730500.0
```

`df4 = df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates().sort_index()` returns a dataframe that is similar to `df3`.

But `df3` and `df4` are still different.

```
> df4
           Adj Close                          Close                          \
                GBTC         QQQ         TLT   GBTC         QQQ         TLT   
Date                                                                          
2018-12-31     3.965  152.132996         NaN  3.965  154.259995         NaN   
2019-01-02     4.620  152.744461         NaN  4.620  154.880005         NaN   
2019-01-02     4.620         NaN  117.461304  4.620         NaN  122.150002   
2019-01-03     4.520  147.754257         NaN  4.520  149.820007         NaN   
2019-01-03     4.520         NaN  118.797966  4.520         NaN  123.540001   
2019-01-04     4.530  154.075851         NaN  4.530  156.229996         NaN   
2019-01-04     4.530         NaN  117.422844  4.530         NaN  122.110001   
2019-01-07     4.860         NaN  117.076653  4.860         NaN  121.750000   
2019-01-08     4.960         NaN  116.768936  4.960         NaN  121.430000   
2019-01-09     4.710         NaN  116.586197  4.710         NaN  121.239998   
2019-01-10     4.320         NaN  115.836174  4.320         NaN  120.459999   
2019-01-11     4.320         NaN  116.288139  4.320         NaN  120.930000   
2019-01-14     4.470         NaN  115.855431  4.470         NaN  120.480003   

            High                           Low                           Open  \
            GBTC         QQQ         TLT  GBTC         QQQ         TLT   GBTC   
Date                                                                            
2018-12-31  4.15  154.979996         NaN  3.95  152.710007         NaN  4.140   
2019-01-02  4.65  155.750000         NaN  4.13  150.880005         NaN  4.155   
2019-01-02  4.65         NaN  122.160004  4.13         NaN  121.339996  4.155   
2019-01-03  4.62  153.259995         NaN  4.32  149.490005         NaN  4.325   
2019-01-03  4.62         NaN  123.860001  4.32         NaN  122.230003  4.325   
2019-01-04  4.65  157.000000         NaN  4.41  151.740005         NaN  4.585   
2019-01-04  4.65         NaN  122.559998  4.41         NaN  121.650002  4.585   
2019-01-07  4.94         NaN  122.650002  4.74         NaN  121.620003  4.740   
2019-01-08  5.08         NaN  121.940002  4.84         NaN  121.389999  4.895   
2019-01-09  5.02         NaN  121.430000  4.63         NaN  120.800003  5.015   
2019-01-10  4.46         NaN  121.410004  4.16         NaN  120.339996  4.455   
2019-01-11  4.49         NaN  121.269997  4.25         NaN  120.680000  4.410   
2019-01-14  4.55         NaN  121.010002  4.14         NaN  120.239998  4.145   

                                     Volume                          
                   QQQ         TLT     GBTC         QQQ         TLT  
Date                                                                 
2018-12-31  154.470001         NaN  3829000  53015300.0         NaN  
2019-01-02  150.990005         NaN  2948200  58576700.0         NaN  
2019-01-02         NaN  121.660004  2948200         NaN  19841500.0  
2019-01-03  152.600006         NaN  1503000  74820200.0         NaN  
2019-01-03         NaN  122.290001  1503000         NaN  21187000.0  
2019-01-04  152.339996         NaN  2020700  74709300.0         NaN  
2019-01-04         NaN  122.339996  2020700         NaN  12970200.0  
2019-01-07         NaN  122.620003  2676600         NaN   8498100.0  
2019-01-08         NaN  121.690002  2653200         NaN   7737100.0  
2019-01-09         NaN  121.260002  2778000         NaN   9349200.0  
2019-01-10         NaN  121.279999  3799800         NaN   8222900.0  
2019-01-11         NaN  120.830002  1218500         NaN   5786900.0  
2019-01-14         NaN  120.900002  2581600         NaN   6730500.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but this seems to be `df3`.

```
pd.concat([df1.stack(), df2.stack()]).sort_values(by='Date').drop_duplicates().unstack()
```

Here is the documentation for reshaping in pandas which may shed more light on stack and unstack operations. The multi-index in the headers you can "stack" to the rows, and then squish the two dataframes together with concat. The drop duplicates is needed since you are grabbing the same symbols in both dataframes over overlapping date ranges. Then to go back to the orignal format just unstack it.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html